# Calculating $ \lim_{b \to a} \frac{a \cdot (a + \sqrt{a^2-b^2}) - b^2}{a \cdot (a - \sqrt{a^2-b^2})-b^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I need to find the limit of:

$$ \lim_{b \to a} \frac{a \cdot (a + \sqrt{a^2-b^2}) - b^2}{a \cdot (a - \sqrt{a^2-b^2})-b^2}$$

I've tried throught "rationalization" and completing squares... This is my work so far (i'm learning by myself limits since my teachers doesn't respond any email and they are not making lectures, just pdf's... I'm trying to do my best, help pls). Also is there any good book or suggestion to learn limits .

\begin{align*}&\lim_{b \to a} \dfrac{a \cdot (a + \sqrt{a^2-b^2}) - b^2}{a \cdot (a - \sqrt{a^2-b^2})-b^2} \cdot \dfrac{(a-\sqrt{a^2-b^2})}{(a-\sqrt{a^2-b^2})} \\=&
  \lim_{b \to a} \dfrac{a[a^2-(a^2-b^2)]-b^2(a-\sqrt{a^2-b^2})}{a[(a^2-\sqrt{a^2-b^2})^2] -b^2 (a-\sqrt{a^2-b^2)}}\\
   = &\lim_{b \to a} \dfrac{-ab^2-ab^2+b^2(\sqrt{a^2-b^2})}{a[(a^2-(\sqrt{a^2-b^2})^2] -b^2 (a-\sqrt{a^2-b^2)}}\\
    =&\lim_{b \to a} \dfrac{-2ab^2+b^2(\sqrt{a^2-b^2})}{a[(a^2-(\sqrt{a^2-b^2})^2] -b^2 (a-\sqrt{a^2-b^2)}}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Didn't you ask this question yesterday? Don't rationalise. Just simplify.

Comment: No. There is an easier way. Just multiply by that a in both numerator and denominator. Then bring a square - b square forward in both again. Then take out the part under sqft as common multiple and then cancel it out. If you are still stuck, will provide details.

Comment: I assume $a>0$ and $b$ approaches $a$ from the left?

Comment: $a>b$ and $a,b \in R^+$

Comment: So from the starting equation, you can just factor out $\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$ from both numerator and denominator.

Comment: Titles should be informative and relevant to the question. Not to the length of time you've been spending on said question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Notice: \begin{align}a \cdot (a + \sqrt{a^2-b^2}) - b^2 &= (a^2-b^2) +a\sqrt{a^2-b^2} \\&= 
\sqrt{a^2-b^2}(\sqrt{a^2-b^2} +a)\end{align}

and \begin{align}a \cdot (a - \sqrt{a^2-b^2}) - b^2 &= (a^2-b^2) -a\sqrt{a^2-b^2} \\ &= 
\sqrt{a^2-b^2}(\sqrt{a^2-b^2} -a)\end{align}

So  \begin{align} \lim_{b \to a} \dfrac{a \cdot (a + \sqrt{a^2-b^2}) - b^2}{a \cdot (a - \sqrt{a^2-b^2})-b^2}=  \lim_{b \to a} \dfrac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}+a}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}-a}  \end{align}

Now it should be easy...

Comment: Thanks so much!! I didn't see it. Thanks thanks!!!!

Comment: Very fast and more clear. My upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

Let
$b = a-x$
where $x > 0$.

$\begin{array}\\
f(a, b)
&=\dfrac{a \cdot (a + \sqrt{a^2-b^2}) - b^2}{a \cdot (a - \sqrt{a^2-b^2})-b^2}\\
&=\dfrac{a \cdot (a + \sqrt{a^2-(a-x)^2}) - (a-x)^2}{a \cdot (a - \sqrt{a^2-(a-x)^2})-(a-x)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{a(a + \sqrt{2ax-x^2}) - a^2+2ax-x^2}{a(a - \sqrt{2ax-x^2})-a^2+2ax-x^2}\\
&=\dfrac{a\sqrt{2ax-x^2} +2ax-x^2}{- a\sqrt{2ax-x^2}+2ax-x^2}\\
&=\dfrac{a\sqrt{x}\sqrt{2a-x} +2ax-x^2}{- a\sqrt{x}\sqrt{2a-x}+2ax-x^2}\\
f(a, b)+1
&=\dfrac{a\sqrt{x}\sqrt{2a-x} +2ax-x^2}{- a\sqrt{x}\sqrt{2a-x}+2ax-x^2}+1\\
&=\dfrac{a\sqrt{x}\sqrt{2a-x} +2ax-x^2- a\sqrt{x}\sqrt{2a-x}+2ax-x^2}{- a\sqrt{x}\sqrt{2a-x}+2ax-x^2}\\
&=\dfrac{4ax-2x^2}{- a\sqrt{x}\sqrt{2a-x}+2ax-x^2}\\
&=\dfrac{4a\sqrt{x}-2x^{3/2}}{- a\sqrt{2a-x}+2a\sqrt{x}-x^{3/2}}\\
&\to 0
\qquad\text{as }x \to 0\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Well, it works. But it takes courage to dive into computations like these. How did you think about computing $f(a,b)+1$ ?

Comment: The dominant term in both the numerator and denominator were the same but with opposite signs. So adding 1 would cancel out in the numerator.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer : This method is probably overkill, you can make do with simpler arguments on limits.

What you want to do is find estimates of the numerator and denominator.

The main tool here is the following estimate for $y \rightarrow 0$ : $\sqrt{1+y} = 1 + O(y) $, where $O(y^r)$ means : something that is comparable to or smaller than $y^r$ as $y$ tends to $0$.

For simplicity, we will write $x= b-a$. Note that $x<0$.

So here, the numerator can be estimated as : $a^2 + a\sqrt{a^2-(a+x)^2}-(a+x)^2 = a^2 + a^2\sqrt{1-(1+\frac{x}a)^2}-(a+x)^2 $

$$\begin{aligned}&= a^2 + a^2\sqrt{2\frac{-x}{a} + O(x^2)} - a^2 + O(x)\\&= \sqrt{2}a^{\frac32} \sqrt{-x + O(x^2)}  + O(x)\\&= \sqrt{2}a^{\frac32} \sqrt{-x} \sqrt{1 + O(x)} + O(x)\\&= \sqrt{2}a^{\frac32} \sqrt{-x} (1+ O(x)) + O(x)\\&=  \sqrt{2}a^{\frac{3}32} \sqrt{-x} + O(x\sqrt{-x}) + O(x)\\&=  \sqrt{2}a^{\frac32} \sqrt{-x} + O(x)\end{aligned} $$

Similar computations tells us that the denominator is equivalent to $ -\sqrt{2}a^{\frac32} \sqrt{-x} $.

So the limit should be $-1$.

Comment: Thanks you so much! this is a different approach, I will try it :D!

Comment: In fact, I can all but hear one of my maths teachers say "You want industrial methods that do not rely on algebraic equalities. Hoping for algebraic simplifications is uncivilised." He didn't mince words, but well...

Comment: I would love to learn math deep enough to do that kind of answers, but because the pandemic my first year of math has been online.
I know I need to study as much as I can, but is there any suggestion to really understand and not just applying formulas, any textbook? :(

Comment: If you haven't done so yet, you can try looking for questions about finding good textbooks. If there are none, you can try asking one yourself.